# flash cards showing blank card android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a flash card app in android.

For some reason when you hit the button for next card it will randomly show either the next card or a blank card. Sometimes it will be a whole heap of blank cards then one with information.  Please find the code below. I am new to creating apps but have done java in the past, it works perfectly in netbeans but not when you run the app.

I want the cards to only appear once thats what the num arraylist is for, it holds the index numbers for the names arraylist. so it appears once but will show blank cards when it shouldnt be. eg: card with info, card without info, card with info. sometimes it will show multiple empty cards then one with info, that is my problem.

I know i havent commented the code,

The first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
CharacterArray Character = new CharacterArray();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Character.createArrays();
}

/**
 * Called when the user taps the Start button
 */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Character.getCharName();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, Character.card());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

The second activity where the cards are called:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

public CharacterArray Character = new CharacterArray();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
    ;
}

public void refresh(View view) {
    Character.getCharName();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, Character.card());
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

The methods to get the cards, There are arraylists and the arrays are created correctly and the string arrays are inputted correctly. the CharacterNames array is just an array with names in them. the num array just has index numbers inputted and checked:

```
    public void getCharName() {
    RandomNumGen();
    mMessage = "";
    message = "";
    while (num.contains(mRandom)) {
        RandomNumGen();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CharacterNames.size(); i++) {
        if (i == mRandom) {
            mMessage = CharacterNames.get(i);
            if (i == mRandom && CharacterNames.contains(mMessage)) {
                num.add(mRandom);
                card();
            }
        }
    }
}


public void RandomNumGen() {
    mRandom = (int) (Math.random() * CharacterNames.size());
}


public String card() {
    String[] array;
    for (int y = 0; y < names.size(); y++) {
        if (Arrays.asList(names.get(y)).contains(mMessage)) {
            array = (names.get(y));
            for (String array1 : array) {
                if (array1 != null && array1.length() > 0) {
                    message += "\n" + "\n" + (array1);
                }
            }
            Arrays.fill(array, null);
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

I hope thats enough information to help.

Thank you so much for understanding an helping me

activity display message xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="refresh"
        android:text="@string/next_char"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="Next character" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

enter code here
```

Comment: I had the same problem with Math.random. I guess its not so random. I had to use Collection.shuffle. Or else, you can set rule, if (blank card) then next card must not be blank

Comment: ehsan rosdi math.random wasnt a problem since i was putting the number in the num arraylist, and how would you set the rule? like i said, when i ran the java code in netbeans it ran correctly everytime, but once i copied it into android studio and ran the app that was when i had blank cards coming up

Comment: Ow, sorry. My bad. Missunderstood your question :D. If that's the case, I had no idea.

Comment: Ehsan Rosdi, no problem, sorry if i came across harsh, i also forgot to mention that the cards are to only come up once and thats it, so thats why it didnt matter for the random generator, ill edit the question. sorry again if i upset you

Comment: Can you share the XML of DisplayMessageActivity?

Comment: Susmit Agrawal, sure please find it added to the main post